# Regular Expression Match Without Final Character

Tags: regex, isapi-rewrite

I'm trying to match any requests for a url that do not have a folder character (/) or end with an extension (.aspx). I can ignore querystring values and fragments in the regular expression for now. So far I have the following.

```
^([\w-/]+)(?!\.aspx|/)$
```

However, if I run this expression it selected the final / in the group which I don't want it to do. The goal is to append .aspx to urls that do not have it specified using Isapi ReWrite and then forward the request onto the .NET engine.

**the example below shows all characters in a current match in bold**

asd.aspx
**this**
something.aspx
**this/test/**   (dont want the final /)
**this-test/**   (dont want the final /)
**this-test**
**this-test/that/test**

Can anyone suggest an expression that would not select the final / if found in the expression?

Comment: Maybe you're trying to do too much with a regular expression?

Comment: Either your first sentence is wrong, or your regex and examples are wrong. Do you want to match all string that don't have a slash or .aspx at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a look-behind assertion:

```
^([\w-/]+)(?<!/|\.aspx)$
```

Comment: I guess your regex engine allows variable-width look-behind assertions then?

Comment: @Douglas Leeder: The look-behind has a fixed width: either one or five characters. Variable width would be to allow an infinite upper bound like `*` or `+` have.

Answer (score 1):

Move the / outside the group ():

```
^([\w-/]+)(?!\.aspx)/?$
```

Comment: Won't the /? never match, because the greedy + will always take it?

Comment: The look-ahead assertion `(?!\.aspx)` as ther is nothing behind the end of the string.

Comment: It's a negative look-ahead assertion - I can't see how the final /? will ever match anything (i.e. it will always be the 0 of {0,1}).

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence doesn't match your regular expression or examples.
It seems to me that you want:

1. If the string ends with `.aspx` don't process further.
2. Otherwise if the string ends with `/` remove that slash.
3. Process the string.

Maybe you're trying to do too much with a regular expression?

Why not explicitly test for your extension (.aspx), and if you don't have that then detect a terminal slash and remove it, before extra processing of the string?

That is to say: I'm sure it's possible to create a regular expression, with negative lookahead, that will do 1 & 2, but wouldn't it be clearer to do it explicitly.

You might also want to test some more examples:

```
foo/bar/.aspx
foo/bar.aspx/
foo.aspx/bar
foo.aspx/bar/
```

Just to be sure you know what you're expecting as output.

Comment: I checked the examples you supplied Douglas and thankfully they don't match using the regex which Gumbo supplied. Good thought though +1.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the / from the regex and add it outside and specify that it can have 0 or 1 occurrence.

^([\w-/]+)(?!.aspx)(/){0,1}$

Comment: ? is shorthand for {0,1} and there is no need to group the trailing /

Comment: you are right, but I didn't see the ? in your answer before, may be I miss that.